# How to identify the script file from where HSQL datatbase is populated?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hsqldb

There is an already existing Java project that extensively uses Hibernate and Spring. And for unit testing it uses an in-memory HSQL data base. I am trying to figure out WHERE this database is getting populated from.

Can someone tell whence I can start looking? Or how to find the file containing the script for creation the tables?

Btw, the tables DO get created. That I confirmed by opening the Database Manager.

Answer (score 0):

If your connection URL begins with `jdbc:hsqldb:mem:` then this is not populated by HSQLDB but by Hibernate or Spring.

If the connection URL begins with `jdbc:hsqldb:file:` then the specified file path is the location of the HSQLDB .script file.